Problem with Kafka connection in Python script (DNS lookup failure with Kafka)
I am following an old tutorial on Youtube to create a data pipeline; I have written my Docker compose file verbatim but get the following error when I try to run one of my Python functions: "WARNING - DNS lookup failed for broker:9092, exception was [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known. Is your advertised.listeners (called advertised.host.name before Kafka 9) correct and resolvable?" Any clue what the issue could be?
The tech stack is:

Python

Docker

Apache Zookeeper

Apache Spark

Apache Airflow

Apache Kafka

Cassandra

PostgreSQL


I have tried editing the advertised listeners as the error suggests but this hasn't helped me at all. I will provide a sample of my docker compose file and also a link to the video and which point to watch from to understand the issue.
Here is a link to the video, watch from 17:14 to 21:29 to see how he builds the Docker Compose file.
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.6.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s 
      retries: 5
    networks:
    - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.6.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on: 
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://broker:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema_registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', 'nc -z localhost 9092']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s 
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.6.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'curl', '-f', 'http://localhost:8081']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.6.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent

networks:
  confluent:


Your advertised listener should contain localhost, assuming your Python code (which wasn't shown) is not running in a container. Otherwise, between two containers, you need to use port 29092, the other advertised listener (they should not use the same hostname, for the same protocol)
